# IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.x crashes when multiple windows are open

Tags: intellij-idea

New issue from **v2022.3.x**

**v2022.2.x** is ok

Already tried:

- clear-caches

  disable installed-plugins

  delete C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\

  delete C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\JetBrains\

  new installation

It seems that the antivirus is detecting something and closes the IDEA 
    I tried with two different antivirus and they both doing it 
    SentinelOne and Symantec 
    disabling them solves it (which is not a solution)

the antivirus doesn't close it if only one window is open 
    the antivirus doesn't close it in v2022.2.5 with multiple windows

Comment: Nope, not seeing it.  How much memory do you have?   Add more.  It never hurts.

Comment: thanks @duffymo. not a memory issue - I'm giving him 7g and he doesn't get near to it

Comment: I run IntelliJ 2022.3 on a MacBook Pro with 16GB RAM.  I've never had it crash in a year, no matter how many windows I have open.

Comment: I never had it crashed as well - till 3 weeks ago : )  I'm on Windows - anyone else on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I have IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 on Archlinux with 8 GiB RAM and faced the same problem. When Intellij run the RAM consumption is extreme and crash OS. Solution was to make swap partition (6 GiB). I think what 16 GiB RAM have to solve issue too.

Comment: I got 64GB ram and the issue is the same.